# Error on In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app on the App Store and it has an in-app purchase feature.
The in-app purchase worked for months with no problem, but suddenly it stoped working on the receipt validation.
I don't know why, since nothing on the code changed.

Does anyone can shade a light on this?
Did Apple recently changed something regarding in-app purchase?

Thanks a lot!
Eduardo Rangel

Comment: However you also need to change PurchaseReceipts in the main function otherwise this only works in sandbox environment and not in the App Store so people still won't be able to make purchases all the times and fails most of the times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CargoBay third party library to validate receipts, this framework has been a while has been suffering from certificate expiration, and no longer fully work however there is a work around to get it partly working, but I'm not sure if it's your case.

If you are using CargoBay make the following change in `CBPurchaseInfoFromTransactionReceipt` and comment out a section of code which will disable part of local security check.

```
NSDictionary * CBPurchaseInfoFromTransactionReceipt(NSData *transactionReceiptData, NSError * __autoreleasing *error) {
NSDictionary *transactionReceiptDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:transactionReceiptData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil error:error];
if (!transactionReceiptDictionary || ![transactionReceiptDictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {
    return nil;
}

NSString *purchaseInfo = [transactionReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"purchase-info"];
NSDictionary *purchaseInfoDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:CBDataFromBase64EncodedString(purchaseInfo) options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil error:error];
if (!purchaseInfoDictionary) {
    return nil;
}

// Comment this section skipping local purchase validation. It's failing in Sandbox due to the old hardcoded certificate from April 2016, and it will move to Production in mid May 2016.
// Cargobay will still verify the purchase with the Apple Sandbox/Production server after skipping the local verification. Hopefully update hardcoded certificate
// in order to move back to Cargobay repository.

/*
NSString *signature = [transactionReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"signature"];
NSDate *purchaseDate = CBDateFromDateString([purchaseInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"purchase-date"]);

if (!CBCheckReceiptSecurity(purchaseInfo, signature, purchaseDate)) {
    if (error) {
        NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [userInfo setValue:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Cannot extract purchase info from transaction receipt because purchase info failed to validate against its signature.", @"CargoBay", nil) forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        [userInfo setValue:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Purchase info failed to validate against its signature.", @"CargoBay", nil) forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:CargoBayErrorDomain code:CargoBayErrorCannotExtractPurchaseInfoFromTransactionReceipt userInfo:userInfo];
    }

    return nil;
}
*/

return purchaseInfoDictionary;
```

}

Comment: Yes, I'm using CargoBay. Didn't know that the lib is having this problems. Do you know any work around? The best solution is to remove the lib and implement this part myself, right?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can make that change in CargoBay.m and build and update your apps ASAP. and don't forget to accept the answer, thanks